# Event that fires only if the *user* scrolls an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to respond to a user manually scrolling an element that has a scrollbar.

Unfortunately, the `scroll` event occurs *on the same element* in several different circumstances:

- when the user scrolls the element (the only one I’m interested in);
- when the user resizes the window and the element’s scroll position changes indirectly;
- when the user changes the zoom of the page and the element’s scroll position changes indirectly;
- when the code changes the element’s `scrollTop` position programmatically.

Is there any way to isolate only the first case and have a handler trigger only when the user actually literally scrolls the element?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you are looking for but, as said in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll), you can check the `event.target` to verify if your scroll is on the wanted element.

Comment: The event target is the same in all the circumstances that I’ve listed, so no, I can’t use that to discern them.

Comment: Are event targets all like [Object HTMLElement] ? if so did you try to compare JSON.stringify(event.target) ?

Comment: Google Chrome actually shows the actual element when you go `console.log(e.target)`, so I can tell that it’s the same element.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't used event.target atm, i thought that it what it was intended for ... Check Coding Chief answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the bubbling of the scroll event by preventDefault() as much as I can remember.So if you register the scroll event(j-query) on the control and prevent it's bubbling up to the other controls I think is gonna solve what you are looking for.

Comment: I’m sorry, what does my question have to do with bubbling? I don’t see the connection.

Comment: As much as I can understand the problem is that you want the event to trigger only when you are scrolling on the element right?So if you are scrolling on the element and u stop the bubbling the other controls won't be notified about the event.

Comment: @Timwi In each of the callback you don't want the scroll event to be fired, add event.preventDefault() =)

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates what you mean? Because I have no idea what you’re talking about. I have a `scroll` event that fires when I don’t want it to. What good is `preventDefault` now? I still need the code to determine which of the 4 circumstances I’m in, so I’m still at square one.

Comment: You must register the scroll event on the element,afterwards if the  user scrolls on the element and you use preventDefault() the scroll event will affect only the element on which the user scrolled.This IMO solves problem number one.

Comment: It seems to me that you completely misunderstood the question; however, I have no idea how to make it any clearer.